# Graph traversal with edge limits

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

We have a node graph, with three types of nodes:

```
normal
source
destination
```

We are given information about which nodes are source nodes, and which nodes are destination nodes. Source nodes produce a set amount of fluid, that flows towards the destination nodes (we can consider this to always be true). I need to find the total amount of fluid that gets into my destination nodes. Below is a simple example:
[image]
The left graph is a graph that we receive via input, and the right one is one of the possible solutions for it. The green '0' and '1' nodes (blue number) are source nodes, and their respective flow rates are 3 and 9 (both of these nodes have the ability to output at most this amount of fluid). The '3' and '2' nodes are our destination nodes, the fluid flows towards these nodes. both of these nodes have the capacity to handle 3 and 5 flow rate of our fluid. The '4' node is a normal node. The fluid starts out at nodes '0' and '1' and travels through the neighboring edges, and through other nodes, until it reaches the destination nodes. Some notable things: the '4' nodes works as a splitter for the fluid traveling from node '1'. Also note that each edge has a max flow rate, which limits how much fluid can flow through it.

How can I solve this problem? I've read up on graph problems, and I've devised several solution, but none of them worked. Thanks in advance.

**What I have tried:**
After some searching, I found some info about the 'Edmonds-Karp' algorithm, which seems like the way to go, but my implementation of the solver seems to be incorrect, as it outputs '12' instead of '6' for the same input as the example above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <limits>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int bfs(const unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>>& residual_graph, int source, int sink, vector<int>& parent) {
    vector<bool> visited(residual_graph.size(), false);
    queue<int> q;

    q.push(source);
    visited[source] = true;
    parent[source] = -1;

    while (!q.empty()) {
        int current = q.front();
        q.pop();
        for (const auto& neighbor : residual_graph.at(current)) {
            int neighbor_node = neighbor.first;
            int capacity = neighbor.second;

            if (!visited[neighbor_node] && capacity > 0) {
                q.push(neighbor_node);
                parent[neighbor_node] = current;
                visited[neighbor_node] = true;
                if (neighbor_node == sink) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int edmonds_karp(unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>>& graph, int source, int sink) {
    unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>> residual_graph = graph;
    vector<int> parent(graph.size());
    int max_flow = 0;

    while (bfs(residual_graph, source, sink, parent)) {
        int path_flow = numeric_limits<int>::max();

        for (int v = sink; v != source; v = parent[v]) {
            int u = parent[v];
            path_flow = min(path_flow, residual_graph[u][v]);
        }

        for (int v = sink; v != source; v = parent[v]) {
            int u = parent[v];
            residual_graph[u][v] -= path_flow;
            residual_graph[v][u] += path_flow;
        }

        max_flow += path_flow;
    }

    return max_flow;
}

int main() {
    unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>> graph = {
        {0, {{1, 3}, {2, 9}}},
        {1, {{3, 3}}},
        {2, {{4, 4}, {3, 5}}},
        {3, {{4, 2}}},
        {4, {}},
    };

    // Assuming 0 and 1 are the source nodes and 2 and 3 are the destination nodes
    int source = 0;
    int sink = 2;
    int max_flow1 = edmonds_karp(graph, source, sink);

    source = 1;
    sink = 3;
    int max_flow2 = edmonds_karp(graph, source, sink);

    cout << "Total fluid into destination nodes: " << (max_flow1 + max_flow2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATED VERSION**
Note that the updated version is slightly off (instead of outputting 6, the resulting output is 7)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <limits>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int bfs(const unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>>& residual_graph, int source, int sink, vector<int>& parent) {
    vector<bool> visited(residual_graph.size(), false);
    queue<int> q;

    q.push(source);
    visited[source] = true;
    parent[source] = -1;

    while (!q.empty()) {
        int current = q.front();
        q.pop();
        for (const auto& neighbor : residual_graph.at(current)) {
            int neighbor_node = neighbor.first;
            int capacity = neighbor.second;

            if (!visited[neighbor_node] && capacity > 0) {
                q.push(neighbor_node);
                parent[neighbor_node] = current;
                visited[neighbor_node] = true;
                if (neighbor_node == sink) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int edmonds_karp(unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>>& graph, int source, int sink) {
    unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>> residual_graph = graph;
    vector<int> parent(graph.size());
    int max_flow = 0;

    while (bfs(residual_graph, source, sink, parent)) {
        int path_flow = numeric_limits<int>::max();

        for (int v = sink; v != source; v = parent[v]) {
            int u = parent[v];
            path_flow = min(path_flow, residual_graph[u][v]);
        }

        for (int v = sink; v != source; v = parent[v]) {
            int u = parent[v];
            residual_graph[u][v] -= path_flow;
            residual_graph[v][u] += path_flow;
        }

        max_flow += path_flow;
    }

    return max_flow;
}

int main() {
    unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>> graph = {
        {0, {{1, 3}, {2, 9}}},
        {1, {{3, 3}}},
        {2, {{4, 4}, {3, 5}}},
        {3, {{4, 2}, {6, 3}}},
        {4, {{6, 4}}},
        {5, {{0, 12}, {1, 3}}},
        {6, {}},
    };

    int source = 5;
    int sink = 6;
    int total_flow = edmonds_karp(graph, source, sink);

    cout << "Total fluid into destination nodes: " << total_flow << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is called [maximum flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem).

Comment: It's important to show your work so that we can understand your thinking. You wouldn't believe how many questions pop up here where people claim to have done reading, written "several solutions", and that "nothing worked", but inexplicably have nothing to show for it.

Comment: @paddy Thank you for the point, I have updated my question with some code I have written to solve this problem based off of the answer provided by gassa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is called [maximum flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem).

To create a flow network, you can add two auxiliary vertices, source `s` and sink `t`.

Then, for every source node `u` generating `x` fluid, add an edge with capacity `x` from `s` to `u`.

Analogously, for every sink node `v` receiving up to `y` fluid, add an edge with capacity `y` from `v` to `t`.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into this and I've devised an algorithm that should working from my point of view, but it produces the incorrect result - would you mind having a look at it?

Comment: @GalBrot 1. The current solution goes like: find flow from 0 to 2; then **start anew**, on a fresh network, and find flow from 1 to 3. Consider that it's not what you want.

Comment: @GalBrot 2. Related: the solution seems to have lost the influx into vertices 0 and 1, and the receiving capacity of vertices 3 and 4. These numbers have to go __somewhere__ to be considered.

Comment: @GalBrot 3. The solution to both is to **add two auxiliary vertices**, one for source and one for sink. Perhaps after writing the code and stumbling upon this problem, it will be more clear why we want that. If not, do ask again.

Comment: thanks, how exactly would you recommend me going about this?

Comment: @GalBrot Firstly, add vertex 5, source, with edges from 5 **to** 0 and 1 with capacities equal to influx of these vertices. Next, add vertex 6, sink, with edges **from** 3 and 4 to 6 with capacities equal to receiving capacity of these vertices. Lastly, find the flow from 5 to 6.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I've updated my question with an updated version of my code, which takes your advice into account, from my perspective, everything should be working now, but instead of '6' I get a '7' as the result  - do you see anything inherently wrong with my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252544/discussion-between-gassa-and-galbrot).

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:

- Handle multiple sources and destinations as described in @Gassa answer
- Find a path from a source to a destination, using the Dijkstra algorithm
- Find minimum capacity of any link on the path
- Reduce capacity of all links on path by minimum capacity
- Remove any link that now has zero capacity
- Repeat above steps until no more paths can be found.

C++ code implementing this algorithm:

https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/2fdae739a4a4dad3b6ad4c510719078edd3e228b/src/GraphTheory.cpp#L469-L532

The code is part of the PathFinder application.  Documentation on using Pathfinder for calculation the maximum flow through a graph is here:

https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Flows